# perl и его восприятие awk команд

Tags: bash, perl, awk

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со следующей ситуацией.
Существуют две идентичные, по своему выводу, строки, обе запускаются в bash:

```
~/junk$ uptime | awk -F'rage:' '{print$2}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'|tr -d ' '
```

условный вывод:

```
0.08
```

и

```
~/junk$ uptime | grep -o 'load average.*' | cut -c 15-18
```

вывод аналогичен:

```
0.08
```

Если использовать одну из строк в файле junk.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $load = `uptime | grep -o 'load average.*' | cut -c 15-18`;
#my $load = `uptime | awk -F'rage:' '{print$2}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'|tr -d ' '`;
print STDOUT "$load \n";
```

то можно получить вполне ожидаемый вывод:

```
 ./junk.pl
 0.53
```

в том случае, если изменить строку:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#my $load = `uptime | grep -o 'load average.*' | cut -c 15-18`;
my $load = `uptime | awk -F'rage:' '{print$2}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'|tr -d ' '`;
print STDOUT "$load \n";
```

то в выводе можно видеть, что отрабатывает исключительно команды uptime и td ' ', минуя при этом awk-фильтрацию:

```
 ./junk.pl
11:35:10up61days,9:21,63users,loadaverage:0.27,0.31,0.22
```

С чем связано, подобное поведение perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perl сам интерпретирует символы `$1` и `$2`: и заменяет их на второй и первый позиционные параметры скрипта соответственно. Их надо экранировать:

```
my $load = `uptime | awk -F'rage:' '{print \$2}' | awk -F',' '{print \$1}'|tr -d ' '`;
```

ЗЫ: К проблеме не относится, но использовать утилиты вроде grep/sed/awk/cut/tr в perl скрипте — это моветон...

Comment: Спасибо, только подступаю к perl, по этой причине использую то, что знакомо.